# Injecting controller gives empty object AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app, that I am trying to test. The problem is that whenever I try to inject a controller it gives me an empty object.

```
beforeEach( inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
   console.log($controller) // {}
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   ctrl = $controller('MenuCtrl', {
     $scope: scope
   });
   console.log(ctrl) // {}
}));
```

I have attached a sample of my setup with some comments in a JsFiddle, and I would really appreciate some help to figure this out.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimpettersen/tLAW5/7/)

***edit***: I have also tried to do this:

<strike>beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Controllers'));</strike>

Then I get:
    Error: No module: Controllers

***This fixed that problem:***

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('controllers'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Bacon Darwin on the [Angular mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/G8c5UaALcWQ/discussion)
for finding the solution to this. I was trying to call `changeView()` on the controller. However, it is the scope that has this function and not the controller.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,

```
var Controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
```

your test configuration

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Controllers'));
```

should instead be

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('controllers'));
```

with a lowercase 'C', as that is the actual name of this module. You could also use `myApp`, as it depends on `controllers`.

Comment: Ah, of course. That fixed the No module Controller problem, but I still get an empty $controller